# How to mock an if condition for the below code?

Tags: mockito

This is my code:

```
if(a.getObj().getReq()== 5)
  { class.dosomething1(a)}
else
   { class.something2(a);}
```

My Junit class is

```
@InjectMocks
Class1 class;
@Mocks
A a;
@Mocks
B b;

Mockito.when(a.getObj()).thenReturn(b);
Mockito.when(b.getType()).thenReturn(11);
class.method(a);
```

Here I need to go to the else condition but mocking isn't happening since when the function is called actual parameter is passed insted if what mockito returns. Please help me on this. I have to make that if condition false somehow and please note that A and B are API classes I mean these are not defined by me.

Comment: it should be b.getReq() instead of getType();

Comment: Feel free to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28877502/edit) if you've made a typo. Or are you telling us you've figured out the answer?

Comment: Are you sure that the mocks are actually being injected? Try with manual injection instead of @InjectMock.

Comment: The key, as stated in the previous comment, is to verify your mocks are actually injected.  Run your unit test in the debugger and look at the type of your "a" object. If it looks odd, with things like "$Mock" or somesuch in the actual type name, then that's a mock object.

Comment: yes mocks are being injected, but still I am not able to cover else condition

Comment: Can you show us the full method you're trying to mock?